# Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in cake php

Tags: cakephp

I am facing a issue during update query.

MODEL CODE

```
public function resetpassword($key,$password)
{
$aresetpassword = $this->updateAll(array('Register.password'=>$password), array('Register.key'=>$key)); 
return($aresetpassword);
}
```

VIEW PAGE ERROR

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   '8815061c1a6c63398b9a2dfb1f44aae89dd59bfd' in 'field list'

SQL Query:

```
UPDATE `milgyonu_mber`.`registers` AS `Register` 
SET `Register`.`password` = 8815061c1a6c63398b9a2dfb1f44aae89dd59bfd 
WHERE `Register`.`key` = '656abe3991a51c62e860b8d1401e4f49'
```

Event password field is exists in my table.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the [manual](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-updateall-array-fields-mixed-conditions) when using Model::updateAll() you need to manually quote literals in `$fields` argument. So use `array('Register.password'=> '"' . $password . '"')`

Comment: Or even better use `DboSource::value()` to eliminate the potential for this to end up as a possible SQL injection vulnerability. `'Register.password'=> $this->getDataSource()->value($password)`